# Issue with stylizing Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found a custom form style i want to copy. however, it's hard for me to figure out how to integrate the rails into its style since it is much more complicated than examples I've been
able to find.

Specifically, I don't know how to call the specific classes the example uses in my rails app.

I would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to create my rails form in this style:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to do something like:

```
 <%= form_for @listing, html: { class:'form-inline lead-big'} do |f| %>
        <div class='form-group'>
        </div>
 <% end %>
```

and then in between the .form-group div, you can either use the same code that is provided on the Bootsnipp page, or you can use Rails Form Helpers.

So instead of this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="name">Hello, I am <span>Your name</span></label>
   <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="@maridlcrmn" required>
   and
</div>
```

it could be:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :name do %>
        Hello, I am <span>Your name</span>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.text_field :name, id: "name", placeholder: "@maridlcrmn", required: true %>
   and
</div>
```

See this page for more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Thanks to you as well for the advice. I've tried what you explained and can't get it to work. For more info, it is a form that allows users to create listings. After trying many times I'm still unable to get it in the same style as the bootsnip example. I'd appreciate any other suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Specifically, I think one problem I'm having is with calling the class at the start of the code. It's giving me a "syntax error, unexpected tLABEL". I've tried 'html: {class: "form-inline lead-big"}' and 'class: 'form-inline lead-big'

Comment: Are you using a form_for tag or a form_tag?

Comment: <%= form_for(@listing),  do |f| %>

Answer (score 0):

Really cool form I must add!

Depends if you want to do the form for a model or just submitting info. If for mode, use `form_for` if to submit `form_tag`

```
<%= form_tag some_url_path, method: :get do %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= label_tag :name, raw("Hello, I am <span> Your name </span>")%>
              <%= text_field_tag :name%>
              and
            </div>
           ...
<%end%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've tried what you explained and can't get it to work. I think my form is for a model since it is using form_for instead of form_tag. It is a form that allows users to create listings. After trying many times I'm still unable to get it in the same style as the bootsnip example. I'd appreciate any other suggestion